# Kubernetes dashboard cannot be started

Tags: kubernetes

I create dashboard after I installed kubernetes with kubeadm.

```
kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Wait a while, the pod is crashed like:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700-wq0v4   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   3          3m
```

And  I checked the pod log:

```
kubectl logs -f kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700-wq0v4 -n kube-system                      Using HTTP port: 9090
Creating API server client for https://10.96.0.1:443
Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
Refer to the troubleshooting guide for more information: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.md
```

But I tried it mannually, the url works:

```
# curl https://10.96.0.1:443/version
curl: (35) Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version.
```

Have anybody encountered this issue before? or help me?

Answer (score 0):

I execute the following command:

```
rm -rf ~/.kube
```

Now it works. still a bit strange :-(